# Restrict User to select/change Web-content

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, web-content

**Liferay 6.1 CE GA2**

How can I remove "Select" / "Add Web Content" buttons so that user cannot change content of web content display?

I have removed all permissions except `View` for User for site page and web content display but I still can change web content when I login with user account. Web-content should be selected by admin only and not user.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say what goes wrong with the information you give. One possibility is that the user account you sign in with is a "Site Administrator" or "Site Owner" - in this case, they'd have permission to administer content in that site by default. If you make that user account just an ordinary "User", the permissions should disappear.

If you have custom roles, note that the "Define Permissions" section for roles has multiple occurrences of "Web Content": See the intermediary headers for "Content", "Applications" and "Control Panel". You'll find the relevant parts in the "Content" section.

Page permissions have nothing to do with permissions to content like WebContent.

Comment: It appeared that there was an issue with Authentication hook developer has created and defining roles for authenticated users. Accepting this answer since Define Permissions section for Web Content and Web Content Display portlets is correct section for defining access rules.